# different menu for cards in the same CardScrollView

Tags: android, google-glass, google-gdk

Let say I have a immersion with in 3 different cards in the CardScrollView. Now I want to use a menu on each of those cards. but each respective card in the CardScrollView should have his own respective menu.

Is there a way to accomplish this? I can't seem to find any documentation on this.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
mCardScrollView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        currentPosition = position;
        openOptionsMenu();
    }
});

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.share_menu, menu); //fake call
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    menu.clear();
    switch (currentPosition) {
            case FIRST:
                getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.first_menu, menu);
                break;
            case SECOND:
                getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.second_menu, menu);
                break;
            case THIRD:
                getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.third_menu, menu);
                break;
    }

    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Comment: that works perfectly fine after I added menu.clear(); above the switch. Only problem I seem to have now is that my voice commands won't work. So when I say "ok glass" it won't respond. When I take the OnPrepareOptionsMenu() out it works perfectly fine. Any solution for this?

Comment: Everytime your CardScrollView changes positions (or something happens that requires different voice menu items), try calling invalidateOptionsMenu(). And also,please try to configure your menu items in onPreparePanel(int featureId, View view, Menu menu) not OnPrepareOprionsMenu(). Here it's possible to be the problem.

Comment: I just tried that and that indeed fixed the problem. Only option I want to try now is to not show the menu when a card is tapped. only when "Ok Glass" is being used. tried commenting out the `openOptionsMenu()` call but when  I do that it will always show the first menu. No matter on what card I am I get the menu for the first card. When I use the call it all works fine tho

Comment: My problem lays in the fact that the position is get when the card is tapped. Is there a method to get the current position that you know of?